# Is it possible to store a temporary table automatically in mysql that lasts for a day?

Tags: mysql, caching

I have a large table that takes around 30 seconds to select the way I want it and it gets larger every day. I'd like to be able to store that selection in a temporary table or cache or something so that this doesn't take so much time.

It doesn't bother me that the table/cache that is being queried over the day may be a few hours old, as the speed is more important.

I suppose someone will wonder why the query is taking so long, so here is the query I'd like to cache every day (or create a temporary table):

```
select itemcode, warehouse, quantity 
from transactions 
where (itemcode, warehouse, recordmodified) 
  in ( select itemcode, warehouse, max(recordmodified) 
  from transactions 
  group by warehouse, itemcode ) 
group by itemcode, warehouse
```

(I'm asking about the temp table, but if you have suggestions about a faster query, I wouldn't mind hearing about it).

What is making this so slow is the max(recordmodified) that I use to get just the most recent transaction.

I guess I could simply write code in php to drop the table, make the query and create a new table every morning, but I'm hoping there is a way to do this automatically in MySQL.

Comment: Can you try to explain what result you're trying to create? It's a very odd query.

Comment: But yea using a subquery is probably what's killing you.

Comment: If you create an index on `(itemcode, warehouse, recordmodified)` the subquery will be faster. Also, use a `JOIN` instead of `WHERE IN`.

Comment: A temporary table is only visible in the connection that creates it, and goes away when the connection closes. If you really need to cache this, put it in a regular table.

Comment: If you want to do this every day, you can use the MySQL Event Scheduler to run the procedure that recreates the table.

Comment: @Evert The table contains quantities of inventory for different products at different times. Every time the inventory for a product changes, this table will be updated with a new row that has the new inventory quantity and the time the inventory changed. I am using max(recordmodified) to get the most recent inventory for each product.

Comment: Can you share your full table structure with `SHOW CREATE TABLE` ?

Comment: @Evert CREATE TABLE `transactions` (
 `id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `warehouse` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `itemcode` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `quantity` double(14,2) NOT NULL,
 `recordmodified` datetime NOT NULL,
 `currenttime` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=506475 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: @Andri time to learn about indexes. Your table doesn't even have  primary key. It's super small still so one or two well-placed indexes will likely solve most of your problems.

Comment: @Evert I'd love to learn more about indexes. There is a primary key (id), is that not enough?

Comment: Right, I missed the primary key. You can probably find some resources on other websites to give you a primer on indexes. It's really critical to know this before proceeding.

Comment: @Evert That's amazing, I've never really taken the time to learn about indexes. 5 minutes of googling and I got the time for the query down by 80%.